Why was there a law to help when a husband had an evil spirit over him?
Numbers 5
29 ‘This is the law of jealousy, when a wife, while under her husband’s authority, goes astray and defiles herself, 30 or when the spirit of jealousy comes upon a man, and he becomes jealous of his wife; then he shall stand the woman before the Lord, and the priest shall execute all this law upon her.
A spirit of jealousy is Demonic/ of the flesh…Why was there a law to help when someone had it? It was OT, does that make a difference in this case?
We are taught the following:
Galatians 5:19-21 - Now the works of the flesh are evident: sexual immorality, impurity, sensuality, idolatry, sorcery, enmity, strife, jealousy, fits of anger, rivalries, dissensions, divisions, envy, drunkenness, orgies, and things like these. I warn you, as I warned you before, that those who do such things will not inherit the kingdom of God.
Proverbs 14:30 - A tranquil heart gives life to the flesh, but envy makes the bones rot.
James 3:16 - For where jealousy and selfish ambition exist, there will be disorder and every vile practice.
James 3:14-16 - But if you have bitter jealousy and selfish ambition in your hearts, do not boast and be false to the truth. This is not the wisdom that comes down from above, but is earthly, unspiritual, demonic. For where jealousy and selfish ambition exist, there will be disorder and every vile practice.
Proverbs is OT, why did they have this law in Numbers?

This is not a question about explicating the text.

If it’s not about explicating the text, I don’t know what is.

Anything that asks what the text actually means.  It clearly does not discuss its purpose, and therefore asking after its purpose is not explicating the text.

You can always re-word it so that it sounds more like whatever you’d like it to sound like. I would but I already got an actual answer with an explanation of a text I obviously didn’t understand. Thus, the question.

The problem is that the question is not suitable for this format, not what it sounds like.

I already got my answer whether you deemed it suitable or not. So…

The law of jealousy:
This law was part of the Mosaic Law given to the Israelites after their exodus from Egypt. You asked, "why did they have this law?"
Short Answer: In an era where women's rights were few, God was providing protection and restoration.

There are really two scenarios.
Scenario where the woman has cheated:

The husband suspects his wife of infidelity due to changes in her
behavior or other indirect signs.
His intuition is telling him something is not right, but he has no
concrete evidence or witnesses to prove his suspicions.
This suspicion leads to a spirit of jealousy, causing strife and
conflict within their marriage.

The law provided a means for the husband to confirm his suspicions. If the wife was indeed guilty, the trial by ordeal would reveal her guilt.
Scenario where the woman has not cheated:

The husband becomes jealous and suspicious, even though his wife has
not done anything wrong.
His unfounded suspicions lead to a spirit of jealousy, causing
unnecessary conflict within their marriage.

The law provided a means for the wife to prove her innocence. If she was indeed innocent, the trial by ordeal would vindicate her and the husband would be put to shame.
God’s desire is for both justice and reconciliation. In both scenarios, the law served to resolve issues of jealousy and suspicion within the marriage. It provided a means for the truth to be revealed, whether to confirm guilt or prove innocence. It also served to restore peace and harmony within the marriage.
In a society where women had limited rights, this law also offered some level of protection to women who were falsely accused by their husbands. The reason for this is because the trial by ordeal was under the control of the priest and God, not the potentially jealous husband.
It also, somewhat, acted as a deterrent which promoted faithfulness within marriage.
Finally, the specific laws themselves are not directly applicable to Christians today, however they do show God’s character and His desires for right and united relationships.

Thank you for explicating the text once again. I see you also gave me understanding in a different question.
